# How to combine or merge columns with NULL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to take the below data and transform it into the expected result table.

| INV | ITEM | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INV123 | null | 12.00 |
| INV123 | null | 96.00 |
| INV123 | abc | null |
| INV123 | xyz | null |

Expected result:

| INV | ITEM | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INV123 | abc | 12.00 |
| INV123 | xyz | 96.00 |

Comment: Why is `'ABC'` related to `12.00` and not `96.00`? Why do the values of `ITEM` go from uppercase to lowercase?

Comment: and why does `'XYZ'` (in `INV123`) get re-assigned to `INV124`?

Comment: @Dai sorry, that was a typo on my part. I've corrected it.
Larnu the relationship between the item and the amount doesn't matter.  I just need to merge the rows.

Comment: @zAnthony You still haven't explained why `'abc'` gets mapped to `12.00` and `'xyz'` to `96.00`.`

Comment: @zAnthony _"the relationship between the item and the amount doesn't matter. I just need to merge the rows"_ - in SQL there is no such thing as "doesn't matter": everything has to be strictly defined. If there is no inherent meaning in a single row with values `'xyz'` and `12.00` or `96.00` then those values don't belong in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming mapping the "first" non-null `item` to the "first" non-null `amount` is actually arbitrary, here's one way:

```
WITH items AS 
(
  SELECT inv, item, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inv ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE item IS NOT NULL
), amounts AS
(
  SELECT inv, amount, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inv ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT inv = COALESCE(items.inv, amounts.inv),
  items.item, amounts.amount
FROM items FULL OUTER JOIN amounts
ON items.inv = amounts.inv
AND items.r = amounts.r
ORDER BY COALESCE(items.r, amounts.r);
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BBYJiiDx).

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is used because you probably won't always have the same number of non-null `items` and non-null `amounts` for a given `inv`. However you might also want to handle the case where both columns have a non-null value - do those columns stick together on the same output row, or no?

If the ordering needs to be more deterministic, you need to explain what other data exists in the table to allow you to rank those columns. Or if you want alphabetical for `item` and numerical for `amount`, just change `ORDER BY @@SPID` to `ORDER BY item`/`ORDER BY amount` respectively.